# Yii Module code generation problems using Gii

Tags: yii

I have just used Gii to generate a new module called gig. After generating the module code with Gii, I updated the config/main.php file to include the 'gig' module as follows:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.modules.*',
),

'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'secretpassword',
    ),
    'gig',
),
```

Now, when I try to access the auto-generated Yii module code in my browser as follows:

http://localhost/gig/default/index/

I receive the following error:

DefaultController cannot find the requested view "index".

To fix this problem, I changed the render code in the module's DefaultController.php from this:

```
$this->render('index');
```

to this:

```
$this->render('gig.views.default.index');
```

This change resolved the problem, but I am wondering if I have missed something or if Gii is generating buggy code for modules?  Anybody experience this problem before?  Is my solution correct?

Now that the controller can find the view, I reloaded the page, only to be shown this error message:

Trying to get property of non-object

Turns out that there is a problem with the following code in the index.php view file:

```
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    $this->module->id,
);
```

I am not sure why this is happening.  I tried changing the above code to the following:

```
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    Yii::app()->controller->module->id,
);
```

but this still gives me the same error message, "Trying to get property of non-object".

Any idea what may be wrong?  Am I missing something when setting up the module code?  I am using Yii 1.1.7

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, it was our own stupid mistake.  One of our programmers added a __construct method to the Controller class and forgot to include the $module variable in that method as follows:

```
public function __construct($id='site')
{
    parent::__construct($id);

    //custom code here
}
```

After adding $module variable as shown below, everything works fine now.

```
public function __construct($id='site', $module = null)
{
   parent::__construct($id, $module);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe that I made this mistake today! You saved my day, mate!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the breadcrumbs, simply delete that code block. If you do want them, make sure your Controller.php (which extends CController.php) class has:

```
public $breadcrumbs=array();
```

Then it should work as expected.

I'm not sure why you were having URL/path problems, but check your URL manager in config/main.php to see if there might be a rule that is causing problems. Seems to work for me without any rules, but if you do have some, try putting this first in the rules array:

```
'gig'=>'gig',
'gig/<controller:\w+>'=>'gig/<controller>',
'gig/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gig/<controller>/<action>
```